# How to make textbox appear after user selects specific value from dropddown using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I am iterating through an arraylist using jstl library and creating drop down list.
My requirement is that as soon as the user clicks 'Others' which is one of the options in drop down list, an editable text box should appear.

I googled through various sites and tried using java script to solve the probelm but nothing happens on selecting 'Others'.

jsp code:

```
<form:form method="get" action="ghdgfd">
<c:if test="${fn:length(listOfParams) gt 0}">
    <c:forEach var="temp" items="${listOfParams}">
        <h3>${temp.paramName}</h3>
        <select name="${temp.paramName}" id="${temp.paramName}" class="target1" onchange='CheckColors(this.value,${temp.paramName});'>
            <c:forEach var="temp1" items="${temp.listOfParamValue}">
                <option><c:out value="${temp1}" /></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="${temp.paramName}" id="${temp.paramName}" style='display:none;'/>
    </c:forEach>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</c:if>

</form:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckColors(val1,val2) {
        var element = document.getElementById(val2);
        if (val == 'Others')
            element.style.display = 'block';
        else
            element.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Kindly help..I am new to javascript. Any help will be apprecated!!

Comment: in your function body, you are using "val == 'Others'". use "val1=='Others'" (as per your function parameter)

Comment: Thanks for the correction but still it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, everything is ok. you may place the `alert` in your if-else block to check which is working and use firebug/chrome developer toolbar to check your jsp is generating the output as expected and not using the same id twice for textarea.

Alternatively, You may use the jQuery solution for this. just replace the below code with your function and remove the onclick event handler from select tag.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('select').each(function(){
       jQuery(this).on('change', function(){
         var $this = jQuery(this);
          if($this.val() === 'Others') {
             $this.siblings(':text').show();
          } else {
             $this.siblings(':text').hide();
          }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, it worked..Text box is appearing but if I select 'Others' corresponding to one of the dropdown, text box appears corresponding to each and every dropdown which is not correct.Kindly suggest as I am novice to jquery

Comment: use jQuery's "next" instead of "siblings".  $this.next(':text').show();